# opscode aws cookbook iam role

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, amazon-iam, cookbook

I am trying to use aws cookbook with iam roles, but when I trying to not include aws_access_key and aws_secret_access_key in the aws_ebs_volume block, the chef keep showing an error: RightAws::AwsError: AWS access keys are required to operate on EC2.

I assume when cookbook mean omit the resource parameters aws_secret_access_key and aws_access_key, I just delete them from the block.

```
aws_ebs_volume "userhome_volume" do
   provider "aws_ebs_volume"
   volume_id node['myusers']['usershome_ebs_volid']
   availability_zone node['myusers']['usershome_ebs_zone']
   device node['myusers']['usershome_ebs_dev_id']
   action :attach
end
```

Does anyone have the example of aws cookbook with iam roles please?

update:

1. Do I still need to define aws creeds data bag if I have already have proper iam role attached to the instance?
2. When I use iam role and aws cookbook, what does the was_ebs_volume block look like?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with aws_s3_file, I'm able to download from S3 without Access Keys using AWS CLI or Powershell, but not Chef

Comment: It looks like the S3 provider doesn't support IAM roles, perhaps the EBS provider doesn't either. See this [issue](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/aws/issues/71).

Answer (score 1):

In order to manage AWS components, you need to provide authentication credentials to the nodein one of two ways:

1. explicitly pass credentials parameter to the resource
2. or let the resource pick up credentials from the IAM role assigned to the instance

When you provision the instance, you should assign it the appropriate role in `"Step 3. Configure Instance Details"` (when using the console). The setting "IAM role" for EC2 automatically deploys and rotates AWS credentials for you, eliminating the need to store your AWS access keys with your application. On an instance provisioned this way, you no longer need to include `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_access_key` in the aws_ebs_volume block. 
Here are code examples on how to launch an instance with an IAM role using the IAM and Amazon EC2 CLIs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

and here are some code examples:

http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/12/19/automating-iam-credentials-with-ruby-and-chef/

When you assign the appropriate IAM role during instance provisioning, your code should work without `aws_access_ke`y and `aws_secret_access_key`.

Here are the steps:

1. Set up your S3, Chef server, and IAM role as described here:
   https://securosis.com/blog/using-amazon-iam-roles-to-distribute-security-credentials-for-chef
2. Execute “knife client ./” to create client.rb and validation.pem, then transfer them from your Chef server into your bucket.
3. Launch a new instance with the appropriate IAM Role you set up for Chef and your S3 bucket.
   Specify your customized cloud-init script in the User Data field or command-line argument as described here:

   https://securosis.com/blog/using-cloud-init-and-s3cmd-to-automatically-download-chef-credentials

   You can also host the script as a file and load it from a central repository using an include.
4. Execute chef-client.

Comment: i have an iam role with proper policy setup for the instance.

i could log in this chef client and use "aws s3 ls" and "aws ec2 describe-", however, the chef recipe which have ebs_volume block is fails (which is happen after awscli installed) due to the error message above. i wondered if there is a switch (or attribute i should set in particular to let the aws cookbook know that i am using iam roles)

Comment: Thank you for this information. The keys won´t work without a token. I expanded the answer to include a step-by-step description of the setup. I hope this helps.

Comment: bit confused now.

1. only want to attach volume in chef receipt without specifying aws in data bags but using iam roles. i assume this should be done when instance is launched through aws cookbook, and no need to use another tool (awscli)

2. i do not need to distribute the chef keys at all, it was already done and i have no difficulties to do `knife client list`.

3. with the iam role i specified for the machine, after install awscli, i am already able to describe volumes. but i want to `attach volumes` happens when first chef run, so my other parts of cookbook (create users) can carry on.